# Response.Redirect doesn't work in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, exception, global-asax

I want to redirect to error page when application throw an exception but it doesn't redirect to that page. Here is my code:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StringBuilder theBody = new StringBuilder();

        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(exception, true);
        // Get the top stack frame
        StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(0);
        // Get the line number from the stack frame
        int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

        string file = frame.GetFileName();

        MethodBase site = exception.TargetSite;
        string methodName = site == null ? null : site.Name;

        string type = exception.GetType().ToString();

        theBody.Append("Line: " + line + "<br/>");
        theBody.Append("Method: " + methodName + "<br/>");
        theBody.Append("File: " + methodName + "<br/>");
        theBody.Append("IP: " + Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] + "<br/>");
        theBody.Append("Error Message: " + exception.Message + "<br/>");
        theBody.Append("Error Stack:" + exception.StackTrace);

            Response.Redirect("~/404.aspx", false);
            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();


       ...
    }
```

And I try it like this on a test page

```
 try
        {

            throw new Exception("Test exception!!");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }
```

It doen't redirect 404.aspx keep staying on test page. What should I do to redirect 404.aspx?

Comment: Why don't you use the default asp.net error-page functionality? http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Comment: Also - why are you preparing an email message you never send?

Comment: @Hainesy I didn't show as you can see the "... " there is an email sending code. But thank you for suggestion. I just pust my redirection code to show people in here.

Comment: @cagin But you can't expect code after a redirect to run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set it in web.config as explained in this link http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

```
<system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On"
                      defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" />

        ...
    </system.web>
```

Comment: I did this one  <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/404.aspx" mode="On"></customErrors> but the same result. TestPage doesn't redirect.

Comment: remove the try & catch block .. just add  throw new Exception("Test exception!!"); and it will be redirected to 404.aspx.. Because when you add any exception in a try and catch block you'll be on the same page, but if you remove try & catch block it will go to ApplicationError function in Global.asax then to the default redirect page that was set on web.config.. Hope this will help you

Comment: Yes I remove try catch block and it run. But do I need remove all my try-catch block in my web project? If yes, is it safe?

Comment: it depends on your logic.. adding customErrors tag with default redirect in web.config will result in redirecting to 404.aspx if any exception happens without try-catch block . i.e if you'd like to be on the same page then keep try & catch block.. if you'd like to be redirected to that page you must remove any try & catch block